# How to convert map to string?

Tags: flutter, dart

my obj is:

```
Map myJSON = {
  "name": {"first":"foo","last":"bar"}, 
  "age":31, "city":"New York"
};
```

I want to replace it with the new output Ex:

```
String myJSON = '{"name":{"first":"foo","last":"bar"}, "age":31, "city":"New York"}';
```

Comment: Have you tried jsonEncode?

Comment: @Andrey Turkovsky I tried it, but iam getting same output
Map myJSON = {
  "name": {"first":"foo","last":"bar"}, 
  "age":31, "city":"New York"
};

Answer (score 53):

Use the `convert` class

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
```

Convert string to Map

```dart
json.decode(stringData);
```

Convert Map to string

```dart
json.encode(mapData);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  String jsonString = jsonEncode(myJSON);
  print(jsonString);
```