# How can I store and safe a List of Maps in Flutter using Shared Preferences? (Flutter, SharedPreferences)

Tags: list, flutter, dart, type-conversion, sharedpreferences

I am trying to safe and load a conversation in my Flutter app.
For that I push each message to a List of Maps:

```
  List<Map> messages = [];

  [...]

  messages.insert(0, {"data": 1, "message": "Hello, how are you?"}); //Message from user 1
  messages.insert(0, {"data": 2, "message": "I am fine."}); //Message from user 2
```

Now, how can I safe this data (the messages List) on the local device and load it when starting the app?

I have tried Shared Preferences already but it only allows me to store Lists of type String, not Map.

Can I convert List of type Map to List of type String and then work with it?

Comment: Hi! Use database to store complex data like this messages. Take a look at sqflite - https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is actually only this data which I would like to store. I think it would be easier to convert each Map to a String and then use Shared Preferences with a list of strings. All the other data is stored in Firestore but messages would be very data intensive to store because of a lot reads and writes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT !
**SharedPreferences** stores only data of type:

- String
- bool
- double

In this typical case you'll use the SharedPreferences to store a String type.
To achieve this you'll need to generate a String type from your data.So you will convert a List => String.
To do that here is a very short piece of code that you'll add it to generate your String .

```
List<Map> myData = [map2,map1];
jsonEncode(myData);
```

The idea is to transform your List into Json data so you can store it as String and decode it whene you need it.

Comment: Thank you, this was the key to solve my problem.

Comment: glad that i could help you but actually you can encode the List<Map> into string it will saves you some code lines i did EDIT the piece of code again so you understand what i mean

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. That's a very simple solution, thanks.

Comment: notice that this post got an answer so poeple in same problem would have some solution thanks

Answer (score 1):

**I found this article:** [How to convert map to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57821021/how-to-convert-map-to-string)

**This is my solution:**
I have a class with all my Shared Preferences functions.
Now, when there is a message added to the List of Maps I then call a setMessages function which converts each Map in this List to a String.
This String is added to a new List of Strings.
Then this List of Strings is stored with Shared Preferences.

On initState I call a function to get the List of Strings with Shared Preferences.
For each element in this list I convert the String to a Map.
This Map is added to a List of Maps and then gets returned at the end so the listview can work with it.

**Here is my code:**

```
  static Future setMessages(List<Map> messages) async {
    List<String> messagesString = [];
    messages.forEach((element) {
      messagesString.add(json.encode(element));
    });
    await _preferences.setStringList(_keyUsername, messagesString);
  }

  static List<Map> getMessages() {
    List<String> messagesString =
        _preferences.getStringList(_keyUsername) ?? [];
    List<Map> messages = [];
    if (messagesString.isNotEmpty) {
      messagesString.forEach((element) {
        messages.add(json.decode(element));
      });
    }
    return messages;
  }
```

The json.encode and json.decode solved my problem.
I also considered to work with sqflite and setup a local database like @Mol0ko suggested but in my case it's only this little data which makes this solution for saving and loading chat messages easier for me.